# How to delete rows from column 1 of dataframe based on condition from column 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have seen a lot of answers on how to delete dataframe rows based on a condition.

However, I have a python dataframe with X and Y values.

I want to delete X values in range 3 to 10 and 33 to 40 when y is in range 3 to 37.

How can we do this?

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
               X          Y         Z         
0      34.587329   0.448762  0.572807
1      34.587325   0.700001  0.579152  
2      34.587327   0.950507  0.578303  
3      34.587328   1.199202  0.579037  
4      34.587328   1.445252  0.581698  
...          ...        ...       ...              
20956   0.013592  41.207004  0.585673  
20957   0.013495  40.411135  0.554721  
20958   0.013909  41.701004  0.571247  
20959   0.014094  41.962998  0.578334  
20960   0.014193  42.208740  0.555786
```

Comment: May you provide sample data? I can't see if the numbers are consecutive, sorted or there are other important characteristics.

Comment: Edited question to add dataframe @BillHuang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)

```
hold_x = ~(df['X'].between(3, 10) | df['X'].between(33, 40))
hold_y = ~df['Y'].between(3, 37)


df['X'] = df['X'].where(hold_x | hold_y)
```

You could also use `isin` + `range()`.
the difference is that in this way you can include only the left limit:

```
df['X'].isin(range(3, 10))
```

Comment: I get an error : ValueError: Points cannot contain NaN. The original dataframe does not have any NaN values

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows where the condition is met or put some value (like NaN) in the rows of column X when the condition is met?

Comment: Remove the rows

Comment: then you need `df_filtered = df.loc[hold_x | hold_y]` ,  `print(df_filtered)`